# Burninate [training]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I think we should burninate the [training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training) tag (61 questions).

[training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training) (synonym with [course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/course) and [self-training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-training)) has an interesting tag wiki, which suggests that it is meant to be used (or rather never used) for requests by the OP for training on some programming topic.

> DO NOT EVEN THINK OF ASKING THIS QUESTION. List questions (shopping
>   lists) are not suitable for Stack Overflow and are going to be closed
>   as "Not Constructive" immediately.

In practice, most of these questions involve training some sort of statistical model (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173433/how-to-train-neural-network-incrementally-in-matlab-and-iteratively-combine-the) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300204/opencv-haar-classifier-training-algorithms)) or some question about their training/testing set split (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620312/decision-trees-test-training-data-difference) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420782/classifier-training-percentage)). In both cases I don't think [training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training) is necessary. If the question is about training a particular type of statistical model in some language, then [training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training) adds nothing beyond the tags for the language and statistical model. Questions about training/testing set splits for the most part belong on [crossvalidated.com](http://crossvalidated.com) or could be instead tagged with [training-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training-data).

Given that this tag is being used to mean different things (and therefore fails the "Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts" [test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)) and doesn't seem necessary to me in any of those contexts, I propose burnination.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that tag excerpt to do anything but annoy people trying to ask legitimate machine learning questions.

Comment: How did that wiki even get approved...

Comment: @SnareChops: It was never approved: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11751206/revisions Anyway, it's arguably an improvement over the previous version: "Training is an educational opportunity, usually sponsored by employers, to introduce new concepts and techniques which attendees can apply immediately in their work environment."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merged - but NOT synonymized - with [training-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training-data).

[training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/training) and its former synonyms are no more - I agree that these were just inviting misuse.