# Merge "facet" and "facets" tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I edited a question because it was tagged with [facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facet) (459 questions) and [facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facets) (163 questions) — and removed the one that didn't contain a description. The edit was approved by a moderator. Can/should this be done in bulk?  Note that there are 7 questions dual-tagged with both [facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facet) and [facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facets).

Comment: In serious need of some disambiguation, there are a few questions about C++ iostreams facets, and then a lot about things that are completely different.

Comment: Note: there is no *bulk* retagging. People must go through every question and fix all issues that they encounter like bad titles, grammar and formatting problems, and obviously the tags that they set out to fix.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think the moderators can "merge" tags in an automated way based on, for example, Shog9's answer at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274387/3093387

Comment: @josilber You're right, moderators can merge tags which can be regarded as a bulk retag, but it seems that this is not what should be done here. I have no idea what facet(s) are, so I'm only referring to Ben Voigt's comment that the tags should probably be cleaned up/disambiguated and not simply merged.

Comment: @ArtjomB. True -- if disambiguation is needed then bulk retag is not the correct option.

Comment: Facet is a concept IntelliJ IDEA; facets are the execution. There's also the notion of faceted navigation in Web applications, with a facet as the base unit. Generally the term facet is used interchangeably with its plural form. How do you generally handle the plural in tag names? Disambiguate or conflate?

Comment: Usually plurals are merged (with the singular being kept).  If there is a need for separate tags, then they need to be distinctly named.

Answer (score 2):

It's done. [facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facets) is now a synonym of [facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facet).